# When the Image is null, set another default image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, datatemplate

Can you see this tag:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

But below? What I'm trying to do is, when the Image is null, set another default image. Is this possible?

```
<!-- Grid-appropriate 250 pixel square item template as seen in the GroupedItemsPage and ItemsPage -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard250x250ItemTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="320" Height="240">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderRectBrush}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortTitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayTextBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="48" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`. e.g. something like

```
<Image Stretch="UniformToFill">
     <Image.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Image">
             <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Image}"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Image}" Value="{x:Null}">
                     <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/Default.png"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Watch out for [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of **local values**.

Comment: maybe am I wrong, what it happens is.. I'm using Windows8 and VS2008 in a Grid Application.. and it tells me: the attachable property triggers was not found in style

Comment: You would need to place the `Style.Triggers` in an element which is *not* a `Style` for an error like that to occur, are you sure you have the right structure? `Triggers` is just a normal property of a `Style`, not an [attached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) one.

Comment: Well, as I tell you, I'm using VS 2011 (not 2008, sorry), and as I'm creating a metro application maybe that's the reason

Comment: Doesn't matter what version of visual studio you use, the question is what kind of .NET classes you can use. I don't know if you have such restrictions when targeting metro apps, but triggers have been around since .NET 3.0.

Comment: I have the same problem as @DarfZon: I use Win8 & VS12, .NET 4.5 and copied the exact same code you posted above into my code and get the following error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Triggers'". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need a trigger I typically use a fallback value like below when I need to specifiy a value when the bound value will not convert.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageURI, FallbackValue='SomeImageURI'}" />
```

[Microsoft FallbackValue Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx)